# Are there chainring bolts with covers for SRAM AXS Quarq powermeters for 2x that looks like SRAM's own for 1x?

Tags: chainring, sram, chainring-oval, axs

When building a bike with 12s Force AXS, SRAM/Quarq powermeter, 2x with oval Rotor chainrings, I missed that the supplied bolts with covers (from SRAM/Quarq) where for 1x (i.e. too short and they actually came off during a recent 1600k ultra).

The bolts in question are these: https://www.bike-discount.de/en/sram-red-chainring-bolts

[image]

In the past, I've ridden a lot of bikes with oval chainrings 2x from various brands together with Shimano Di2, and bolts with covers for Ultegra/Dura-Ace 2x are to be found from Shimano, absoluteBLACK, Rotor, et al.

I can't seem to find anything for the SRAM/Quarq spindle. Are there any available? Or should I just go for standard (ugly) chainring bolts?

Answer (score 2):

Just found an elegant solution to this same problem so thought I should share, as using standard chainring bolts without the covers just looks terrible.

You need:
-AXS caps/covers and bolt kit for 1x
-AXS 2x bolt set
-Force CX1 bolt spacer set
-Wheels Mfg 1.2mm chainring spacers (4)

Then the CX1 spacers plus 1.2mm spacers on the inside of small chainring adds just enough thickness for the 2x bolts to work with the 1x covers. It sticks out maybe 3mm so make sure you’ve got clearance, but looks nice because the CX1 spacers are finished and chamfered.

Answer (score 1):

The official answer is you use regular chainring bolts and sleeve nuts for 2x (per the [user manual](https://www.sram.com/globalassets/document-hierarchy/user-manuals/quarq/power-meters/quarq-power-meter-user-manual.pdf)) for the power spider, and the part number (11.6918.004.000) for them is in the [spare parts catalog](https://www.sram.com/globalassets/document-hierarchy/spare-parts/spare-parts-catalog/2023-sram-spare-parts-catalog.pdf).

I have no idea whether there's an aftermarket setup for 2x that gives the same look as the covers.

Answer (score 1):

This site appears to have 2x bolts and covers. Is this what you are looking for?

https://www.excelsports.com/sram-force-etap-axs-chainring-bolt-set

[image]